# QwtPlot showing the wrong date/time

Tags: qt, date, datetime, qwt, qdatetime

I'm using `QwtDateScaleDraw` in Qt to plot a `QDateTime` at the X-axis of a graph.

I use this command to convert the `QDateTime` to a `QwtDate::Double`:

```
tempData->append( QPointF( QwtDate::toDouble( date.at(var) ), data.at(var) ) );
```

The first date/time that I have is

> 01/08/2014 00:00:52

but when I place the data in the graph, the first date is

> 31/07/2014 21:04:52.

I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using:

```
scaleDraw->setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC);
```